# How to order the dataframe'columns names the same way of another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like this: **DF1**

```
text    yellow   blue    red    orange
dfsfs     0       1       1       0
sdfsdf    0       0       1       1
asdasd    1       1       1       1
```

and Another dataframe like this: **DF2**

```
    text    blue   orange    pink   red   black  yellow
    dfsfs     0       1       1        0     0      1
    sdfsdf    0       0       1        1     0      1
    asdasd    1       1       1        1     0      0
```

What's the best way to order the second dataframe'columns(`DF2`) in the same order we have in the first dataframe (`DF1`) considering the names that matchs and the names that dosen't match in last positions?

The output shoud be:

```
text    yellow   blue    red    orange  black  pink
dfsfs     0       1       1       0      0      1
sdfsdf    0       0       1       1      0      1
asdasd    1       1       1       1      0      1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
df2[df1.columns.append(df2.columns.drop(df1.columns))]
```

output:

```
     text  yellow  blue  red  orange  pink  black
0   dfsfs       1     0    0       1     1      0
1  sdfsdf       1     0    1       0     1      0
2  asdasd       0     1    1       1     1      0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use sort by key and supply index to the sorting algorithm where we want our data to be based on the second list.

```
def position(value):
    try:
        return X.index(value)
    except ValueError:
        return len(X)

X = df1.columns.tolist()
Y = df2.columns.tolist()
Y.sort(key=position)
```

The columns from second dataframe is `['yellow', 'blue', 'red', 'orange', 'pink', 'black']`.
Now we can rearrange our database columns using :

```
df2 = df2[Y]
```

This gives us the expected output :

```
text    yellow   blue    red    orange  black  pink
dfsfs     0       1       1       0      0      1
sdfsdf    0       0       1       1      0      1
asdasd    1       1       1       1      0      1
```